# How can I create a MongoDB cluster using multiple/three nodes/servers/machines using a single shell script?

Tags: mongodb, sharding, replicaset

1. How Can I up the 3 config server from a single remote/local terminal ?
2. How Can I up the shard servers ?
3. How can add multiple machines to the shard cluster ?
4. How to create the replica sets in the multi node cluster?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched for answers on StackOverflow that haven't answered your question? Also look at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you will be needing a terminal to up the shard servers

**1 .Script for each shard -**

On every shard u will have a script cluster.sh which will include

```
/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.6/bin/mongod --replSet <shard name> --logpath <logpath of replicaset> --dbpath --port <port no> --shardsvr
```

this should be done for every replica set in that shard

then
connect to mongo client using the port u mentioned in script to up the shard server.

```
config = { _id: <shard name>, members:[
          { _id : 0, host : <ip of the shard : its port no.> }]
```

add all the replica sets here by this command

```
rs.initiate(config)
```

**2. Script for each config server** (cfgserver.sh)

on each machine that will be a config server

you will have a script to up the config server

```
/root/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.6/bin/mongod --logpath <path to store config logs> --dbpath <path to store config data> --port <port no>  --configsvr
```

**3. script in the terminal to up each shard and config servers**

for every shard or cluster

```
ssh 10.x.x.x 'sh /mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.6/bin/cluster.sh'
```

for each config server

```
ssh 10.x.x.x 'sh /mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.6.6/bin/cfgserver.sh'
```

after this all the clusters will be up with desired number of replica sets
and all the config servers will also be running.

all we are left is to add shards to this environment

so it will be done in following way

start mongo client and fire this command for every shard you want to add

```
db.adminCommand( { addShard : "<name of the shard>/"+"ip of that shard:port number" } );
```

name of the shard will be same as we defined in the script for every shard i.e cluster.sh